# Cannot import ctypes for checking admin privileges on Windows platform

Tags: python, uac, penetration-tools

Hello Programmers of Stack overflow,

I am trying to import I library for my code, but whenever I execute my code on PyCharm, i get an error:

```
File "C:\Users\USER\projectextinguish\venv\lib\site-packages\command_runner\elevate.py", line 49, in <module>
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Cannot import ctypes for checking admin privileges on Windows plaform
```

Does anyone know how i can import ctypes?

I have no idea what to do.

code:

```
import os   #self explainitory
from command_runner.elevate import elevate


def admin():
  elevate(mainfirewall)



   admin()   # executes admin function

   def mainfirewall ():
os.system("netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off")              # disables firewall

mainfirewall()         #executes firewall function
```

Comment: The problem is not in importing `ctypes`. The problem is more probably that your code tries to use `command_runner.elevate` while your current user has not an admin privilege. You should show the full stacktrace including your own code.

Comment: @SergeBallesta your wish is my command

Comment: @SergeBallesta what im trying to do here is elevation, i guess i should link the documentation to the library: https://pypi.org/project/command-runner/

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the last part of your error message by installing `command_runner` and **not** installing `pywin32`. I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\ess\venv\lib\site-packages\command_runner\elevate.py", line 43, in <module>
    import win32event  # monitor process
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32event'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\...\ess\venv\lib\site-packages\command_runner\elevate.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Cannot import ctypes for checking admin privileges on Windows platform.
```

The first part of the stacktrace gives the cause: the `pywin32` package is required to have the `win32event` module.

How to fix: install the missing package with `pip install pywin32`

Comment: Thank you @Serge Ballesta i was going to send an email to the auther of the library lol